Perl IO::File dying with error "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at script.pl line LINE" - can't write to file
Trying to open a file handle to write text to, but script keeps failing with the error:
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at C:/Users/USER/Documents/script.pl line 207, <GEN1> line 20001.
 at C:/Users/USER/Documents/script.pl line 207, <GEN1> line 20001.

Example code:
my $fileo = 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\report.txt';

# Open output file handle
my $fho = IO::File->new($fileo, 'w');
say $fho "THIS FILE: $fileo";
$fho->close();

I've checked Perldocs and MetaCPAN regarding module IO:File but I can't see anything wrong with the syntax.
Any ideas?

The file path was wrong. Path did not exist. My bad...

There was an error opening the file.
my $fho = IO::File->new( $fileo, 'w' )
   or die( "Can't create `$fileo`: $!\n" );

No use for the extra layer introduced by IO::File.
open( my $fho, '>', $fileo )
   or die( "Can't create `$fileo`: $!\n" );

